How do i implement a public list with insertion and popping in Tamarin?
I want to have a public list, where different processes can get and put a compartment id (CID).
This is how i create my list:
// Create CFL
rule Create_CFL:
    [Fr(~cid1),Fr(~cid2)]
    --[OnlyOnce('Init_CFL')]->
    [CFL(<~cid1,~cid2,'null'>)]

This is how i pop a CID:
// Requesting CID
rule Get_CID:
    [P(pid),CFL(<cid,tail>)]
    --[Get_CID(pid,cid)]->
    [P_CID(pid,cid),CFL(tail)]


This is how i insert a CID:
// Returning CID
rule Put_CID:
    [P_CID(pid,cid),CFL(tail)]
    --[Put_CID(pid,cid)]->
    [P(pid),CFL(<cid,tail>)]

My restrictions are copied from the manual found here.:
// Define OnlyOnce
restriction executed_once:
    "All tag #i #j. OnlyOnce(tag) @i & OnlyOnce(tag) @j ==> #i = #j"


My problem is that i want to make a sanity check that two processes can pop and insert a cid with the following lemma, but the prove is not terminating because there is a chain of Get_CID, where i don't know how to break it:
lemma sanity:
    exists-trace
    "Ex pid pid2 cid cid2 #i #j #k #l. Get_CID(pid,cid)@i & Put_CID(pid,cid)@j & i<j & Get_CID(pid2,cid2)@k & Put_CID(pid2,cid2)@l & k<l & (not pid=pid2)"



